# How do I format text within a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have items in a `JList` that I can't get to format correctly.

I've created this method in order to do so:

```
private String formatString(String string){
     string = string.trim();

    int SEPERATOR = 20 - string.length();

    for(int i = 0; i<SEPERATOR; i++){

        string = string + " ";
    }

    return string;
}
```

When I output the items in my `JList` into the output window using a system out print it formats fine, but in my GUI it does not:

[image: example]

I'm not sure if this will help you help me better but here is how I am loading my data into the list:

```
    DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();

    while (rs.next()){

        String Expense = rs.getString("Expense");
        String Cost = "£"+rs.getString("Cost");
        String PurchaseDate = rs.getString("Purchase_Date");
        String Description = rs.getString("Description");

        Expense = formatString(Expense);
        Cost = formatString(Cost);
        PurchaseDate = formatString(PurchaseDate);
        Description = formatString(Description);


        String Row = Expense+Cost+PurchaseDate+Description;

        m.addElement(Row);
        System.out.println(Row);
    }
```

Comment: That type of data screams ***`JTable`!*** to me.

Comment: *"not sure if this will help you help me better"*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Hard code some data to replace the DB - it is irrelevant.

Comment: If you're hell bent on this course, I would also suggest a lesson in how to use `String#format`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution, as has already been suggested, is to use a `JTable`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

> When i output the items in my jlist into the output window using a system out print it formats fine, but in my GUI it does not:

To answer your question you need to use a monospaced font.

```
list.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10) );
```

Also, use standard Java variable names. Variable name (Expense, Cost...) should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use \t (you might have to use /t/t if the the text of a field is too long) instead of using spaces OR use a JTable